# TopoJSON or GeoJSON vector tiles in c++

Tags: c++, vector, tiles, geojson, topojson

I want to use TopoJSON/GeoJSON in c++. I'm writing my own tile client and want to replace the png's with Topo JSON tiles. The problem is that I cannot find an example of TopoJSON/GeoJson tile parser in c++ and how to use these.

I can only find and Protobuf alternative here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapnik-vector-tile

Comment: For my GeoJSON parser I used [boost::property_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree.html). The code is small and simple but it is really slow.. and Im planning to write a better parsing in the future. They have an example of how to use it to parse [JSON](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.json_parser).. you can adapt to your case.

Comment: Ah nice. But still i have to define the features of GeoJSON.for json parsing I'm using rapidJSON. It's most of the time 3 times faster than other parsers. Mapnik has a featureset i've just found of TopoJSON: https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/plugins/input/topojson/topojson_featureset.cpp

Comment: quote: "I'm writing my own tile client ". Did you ever wrote this? And if yes, is it available for the world at large?

Comment: Hi, ive sold this to a Company. So no, there will not be a opensource repo for this.

Answer (score 0):

For the JSON parser part you can use any C or C++ JSON parser from the list on the JSON page

I use gason, because it's super fast and has a super simple API (maybe too minimalist, but not a disadvantage for me)

here's a partially complete  TopoJSON/GeoJSON handler (it only handles "Polygon" and "Multi-Polygon" topologies, maybe the most important use cases )

https://github.com/pedro-vicente/render_geojson

the page has all the links for needed dependencies